# Ubuntu:12:10 x11 can't find screen

Tags: 12.10, command-line, xorg, screen

I've just updated my Ubuntu dual boot with windows. And when I satarted it last night the screen said no signal. Just now I have got it to the comand line or something like that and when I run startX It errors and says there is no screen. I have not been able to find any thing to help from googling the error.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me a few times.
If you have an nvidia card, you have to install the linux-headers package and reinstall the nvidia driver.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get reinstall nvidia-current
```